# Going from a time string to a double

Tags: php, time, double

I let users of my website fill in time in an 00:00-23:59 time text input. I then parse it to a double (E.g. they enter 2:30, it will become 2.30). How would I change those times to actual doubles. Say 2:30 -> 2.50, 1:45 -> 1.75 etc... I have been thinking about this and I feel like the answer is simple but I cannot seem to think of it.

Thank you!

Comment: First, your range has one second more than a day, its 00:00-23:59. Second what are you trying to do? What should 23:30 be as a float? You are mixing dates with doubles which is odd. You should probably just get seconds since 00:00 which is easier to do.

Comment: @Samuel is right, there is something odd going here.
Also beware of the users: a text input like the one you are asking is quite complex, so you'll have a lot of errors. this could be more a UX issue, but nonetheless...

Comment: @samual 23:30 should be 23.50. And yea my days are 00:00 - 23:59.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about below function 'convertTime'? Does this work for you?

```
class TimeTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
   function test_convertTime()
    {    
        $this->assertEquals(23.0,convertTime(23.00));
        $this->assertEquals(23.5,convertTime(23.30));
        $this->assertEquals(23.17,round(convertTime(23.10),2));
        $this->assertEquals(24.0,convertTime(23.60));
    }
}

function convertTime($time){
    $secondsPart = ($time - floor($time))*100;
    if($secondsPart == 0){
        return $time;
    }
    $secondsPartAsFraction = 60/$secondsPart;
    $inDecimal = 100/$secondsPartAsFraction;
    return floor($time)+($inDecimal/100);
}
```